Why isn't the %F format specifier working with printf?
I'm encountering an issue while using the printf() function and I'd like to share the details. The two main sources I'm referring to, cplusplus.com and cppreference.com, indicate that I can use the %f and %F format specifiers.
However, when I attempt to use the %F format specifier in Code::Blocks 20.03, I'm unable to get the desired output. While this format specifier is indicated as usable in other sources, I'm puzzled as to why it's not working in my compiler.
code input:
#include<stdio.h>
#include<float.h>

int main() 
{
    float decimal_floating_point = 1.234567;

    float Decimal_Floating_Point = 123.4567;

    printf("decimal floating point = [%f]\n",decimal_floating_point);

    printf("Decimal Floating Point = [%F]\n",Decimal_Floating_Point);
}

code output:
decimal floating point = [1.234567]    
Decimal Floating Point = []

Why am I getting the result Decimal Floating Point = [] instead of the expected Decimal Floating Point = [123.4567]?

Which compiler is code::blocks configured to use, and how exactly is it called?

GNU GCC COMPİLER @dbush

What version, and how exactly is it being called?

Is this the exact code you are compiling and running?

Aside, you won't get 123.4567 anyway unless you change %F to %.4F.

Release 20.03 rev 11983 (2020-03-12 18:24:30) gcc 8.1.0 Windows/unicode - 64 bit @dbush

%f and %F both expect a double argument, but you're passing floats; you may be getting bit by undefined behavior (can't imagine why you'd get empty output, but UB doesn't have to make sense); may be worth declaring those as double and see if you get different behavior.

Godbolt gcc v8.1 does not repro this behavior https://godbolt.org/z/MPrn5s9M6

@WeatherVane: Blah.  You're right.  Ignore me.

An example of %F, used when making format specifier examples. @EugeneSh.

I suspect WSL funniness...

Is it WSL or Msys/Cygwin maybe? FWIW Can't repro on Msys GCC 13.2.0 as well

Could there be a problem with my compiler? %F was working in the online editors on cplusplus and cppreference sites.

MSVC 2015 seems to work.

Please copy and paste the code from this question back to your code::blocks, save the file, recompile and run. And see if it is reproduced.

The comment by @JohnBode advised (unnecessarily) to use double but why are you using float at all? Never use float without a clear reason why you cannot use double, the natural floating point type in C.

@JohnBode float should be promoted to double per C11 6.5.2.2p6 and 7

@WeatherVane Using double rather than float is a good idea, but it's not related to the problem. The existing code should work, given an implementation that supports C99 or later.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/11063

The %F format specifier was added to the C language by the 1999 ISO standard.
Apparently the implementation you're using includes a C runtime library whose printf function doesn't support %F.
In this case, %f and %F will produce exactly the same output. The output differs only for infinities and NaNs; %F produces INF, INFINITY, or NAN instead of inf, infinity, or nan, respectively.
Note that the version of your compiler doesn't affect this. The compiler (gcc in your case) will just generate a call to the printf function. It's the runtime library that implements that function. The compiler and the runtime library are components of a C implementation.
It's not uncommon for C implementations for Microsoft Windows to combine a reasonably modern compiler like gcc with an old version of Microsoft's C runtime library.
(Incidentally, the identifiers decimal_floating_point and Decimal_Floating_Point are misleading. Floating-point values are almost certainly stored using binary floating-point, typically IEEE. Decimal floating-point is permitted but rare.)

"Apparently the implementation you're using includes a C runtime library whose printf function doesn't support %F" do you have a reference? Apparently gcc 8.1.0 supports even C11.

@ChukwujiobiCanon You missed the "Note that the version of your compiler doesn't affect this. The compiler (gcc in your case) will just generate a call to the printf function. It's the runtime library that implements that function" part.

Yea I missed that. Thanks.
